# using data from a txt file in python

Tags: python, string, text-files

I'm learning python and now I'm having some problems with reading and analyzing txt files. I want to open in python a `.txt` file that contains many lines and in each line I have one fruit and it's price.

I would like to know how to make python recognize their prices as a number (since it recognizes as a string when I use `readlines()`) so then I could use the numbers in some simple functions to calculate the minimum price that I have to sell the fruits to obtain profit.

Any ideas of how to do it?

Comment: Could you give some example lines fo your input file?  Your format specification is quite vague.

Comment: It isn't. It's well understandable. There's a text file, on every line there are two space-separated values: a string and a number. He wants Python to read the second field as a number instead of a string.

Comment: @H2CO3: How do you know it's space-separated?  aix interpreted it to be comma-spearated.  And it also might be a CSV file exported from Excel, so we have to deal with quotes, or whatever.

Comment: sorry, you're right. I didn't read it carefully enough...

Answer (score 1):

If the name and the price are separated by a comma:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    name, price = line.rstrip().split(',')
    price = float(price)
    print name, price
```

Comment: well sorry I know I was quite vague but you really helped me a lot, Thank you =)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your values are space-separated, you can read in your file into a list of tuples using:

```
# generator to read file and return each line as a list of values
pairs = (line.split() for line in open("x.txt"))  
# use list comprehension to produce a list of tuples
fruits = [(name, float(price)) for name, price in pairs] 

print fruits
# will print [('apples', 1.23), ('pears', 231.23), ('guava', 12.3)]
```

Note that [`float()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#float) was used to convert the second value (`price`) from str to a floating point number.

See also: [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/genexpr.html).

---

To make it easy to look up prices for each fruit, you can convert your list of tuples into a dict:

```
price_lookup = dict(fruits)

print price_lookup["apples"]
# will print 1.23

print price_lookup["guava"] * 2
# will print 24.6
```

See: [`dict()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I first was learning Python, coming from Perl. Perl will "do what you mean" (or at least what it thinks you mean), and automatically convert something that looks like a number into a number when you try to use it like a number. (I'm generalizing, but you get the idea). The Python philosophy is to not have so much magic occurring, so you must do the conversion explicitly. Call either `float("12.00")` or `int("123")` to convert from strings.